# What do we mean by extending a function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

For the function $\ f:(0, \infty) \to\mathbb{R}$ given by

$\ f(x) = x^2 \sin{\frac{1}{x}}$,

show that there is a differentiable function $\ g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ that extends f.

**My Question:**

Is

$\ g(x) = \begin{cases}x^2 \sin(\frac{1}{x}) & x \ne 0 \\
0 & x = 0
\end{cases}$

a possible answer to the question ?

Comment: $g$ "extends" $f$ just means $g(x)=f(x)$ when both defined.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, $lim_{x\rightarrow 0}{{g(x)-g(0)}\over{x-0}}$

$=lim_{x\rightarrow 0}xsin({1\over x})=0$, this shows that $g$ is differentiable at $0$